# Update Core Data Object which contains many value

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I use a One-To-Many relationship database in Core Data for an iOS app focused on athletics.

Each sport session has at least 4 "smartData" objects associated with it. As time goes on, more smartData objects are created (possibly more than one hundred). A "smartData" object is a date + a score (a double).

I would like to know how to update all the scores associated with the last session. When I tried to use a for loop and didn't encounter a crash, it replaced the whole set of scores for only one score, when obviously, I wanted to replace a set of scores for another set of scores.

// Fetching the session and associated scores

```
// Fetch core data in the background and get the last session

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MMASession"];
NSArray *results = [[TBCoreDataStoreS1 privateQueueContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                          error:nil];



self.lastMMASession = [results lastObject];

NSManagedObject *smartDataOfLastSession = [lastSession valueForKey:@"smartData"];
```

I understand everything up until this point. I have the smartData of the last session, but I just don't know how to replace the whole set of scores. I have an NSArray property called newScores which contains the new set of values.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.newScores count]; i++) {
    [smartDataOfLastSession setValue:self.smartScores[i] forKey:@"smartScore"];
 }
```

At best, this approach replaces the set of values for one value. I understand my error but anyone could point me towards a solution, it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your own `NSManagedObject` subclass.

In my case, I have a `xcdatamodel` like below.

[image]

Then, You can create the `NSManagedObject` subclass via `Xcode's File > New > File`

[image]

Now, you have the `NSManagedObject` subclass and the wizard made instance methods you need.

[image]

As you see, User.gamble is a NSSet type which has allObject method.

[image]

You can get all gambles with `[user.gamble allObject]`.

Here's an example of my case :

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
for(User *user in result)
{
    for(Gamble *gamble in [user.gamble allObjects])
    {
        // DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
}
```

In your case, it will be `[session.smartData allObject]`.